# $(selector).on( events, descendant , handler ) – how to reference descendant? $(this) gets selector

Tags: jquery

```
$("#wrapDiv").on( "click", ".el", function(){
   //do sth
   //how to reference .el here?
   //$(this) references #wrapDiv
})
```

How can I reference descendant in jquery `on()` event?

Comment: Please post a JsFiddle $(this) should reference the descendant.

Comment: $(this) should reference the element being clicked on.

Comment: I see damn. I have to modify the Q. Gimme few secs. Sorry

Comment: Ok I made a mistake. Few people here found out I needed something like `event.target` (my issue is more sophisticated but this is the base). Thank you all and please mark this for close or deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for target of the event:

```js
$("#wrapDiv").on( "click", ".el", function(ev){
   //do sth
   //how to reference .el here?
   $(ev.target).html("Clicked here");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` should already return the correct source of the event.

However, I think what you're looking for is the event's target.

```
$("#wrapDiv").on( "click", ".el", function(event){
   //do sth
   //how to reference .el here?
   //$(this) references #wrapDiv

   //event.target references .el or anything within it
   console.log(event.target);
})
```

`event.target` returns the lowest element originating the click.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` will reference the descendant, unless none specified.

I've made a fiddle for proof :)

HTML:

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <label id="I'm label">asdasd</label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#someDiv').on('click', 'label', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')); 
})
```

### Fiddle